# About saving value of expression in shell programming

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm just so stressed struggling about this simple grammar.
I learned in text;
To store value in shell programming, we use `value=$(expression)`.
So I made following script

```sh
#!/bin/bash
address=$1
echo $address
value=$(test -d $address)
echo $value
```

This is a script to find if my input(directory) exists and accessible.

Address shows me the input but `$value` shows nothing.

At least I expected 0 or non-zero but it didn't!

Can anybody teach me how to save the result of test?

Comment: A command substitution saves *standard output,* not the result code. You can certainly set `value=$?` though generally that's probably not actually what you want; see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern

Comment: Also tangentially see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try that for sure

Comment: Did you try typing the command on the bash command line?

Comment: @stark yes I did. But didn't worked..

Answer (score 0):

`test` has no output, but the result of the last command is saved as `$?`, so you could either -

```
value=$(test -d $address; echo $?)
```

or just skip saving it and use the test.

```
if [ -d "$address" ]
then ...
```